# Unix `find` on Win MSYS, no such file or directory

Tags: bash, find, sh

I'm trying run a `git pull` on a bunch of folders. This is what I got so far:

```
find . -type d -name .git \
| xargs -n 1 dirname \
| while read line; do cd $line && git pull; done
```

Problem is that `cd` doesn't work I get a bunch of errors:

```
sh: cd: ./project_one: No such file or directory
sh: cd: ./project_two: No such file or directory
...
```

But when I do `cd ./project_one` it works fine. What's wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the `cd` and subsequent operations in a subshell so that the main process remains in the appropriate directory.

```
... | while read line; do ( cd $line && git pull ); done
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an issue of specifying relative vs. absolute file paths. Change the `.` in the "`find . type -d -name .git ...`" part of your script to `$(pwd)` and directory names should be passed as absolute paths to the while loop:

```
find $(pwd) -type d -name .git \
| xargs -n 1 dirname \
| while read line; do cd $line && git pull; done
```

Try that out and it should work =)

Comment: This works too, up vote, but the other answer has fewer additional chars, xD.